# data not updating while clicking on browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, struts2, yui

I have a page which is displaying some records(news details) each record has a hyper link. The data is coming through Ajax. When I click on a link (news) it is displaying the details of that news in the same window.

Then I deleted that news then I clicked browser back button. Again whatever the news I saw before delete, all those news are displaying.

I am able to see Ajax call at browser console. But, actually the call is not going to action class (I am getting the previous data).

When I click on browser back button. Will the Ajax call go to the action class or not? What will happen when I click on browser back button?

Comment: That is default browser back button behavior, it will not trigger any Ajax call if data is there in the browser cache, what you seeing on back button click, browser is showing from it cache

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi i am able to see the ajax calls on console.

Comment: that will only happen if browser cache is not there, you can check if your action is getting triggered

Comment: that is i am saying i am seeing on console.but action is not triggering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be caching the AJAX results. Try using `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` before your ajax statement and see if that helps.

Comment: i am using YUI ajax.How i can do that in yui

Comment: Apologies, I have not used YUI. If you examine their documentation for their AJAX methods I imagine there will be a variable you can set to false to stop this happening.

Comment: Why do you not mention the YUI in the question? Why do you not tag it as YUI and instead tag it as jQuery? Downvoting.